# Unable to extract product price from column in HIVE table

Tags: hive

I am trying to load data into a regular table from a temporary table in HIVE. Below are the first few rows from the temporary table.

```
ProdNo,ProdName,ProdMfg,ProdQOH,ProdPrice,ProdNextShipDate
P0036566,17 inch Color Monitor,ColorMeg Inc.,12,$169.00,2013-02-20
P0036577,19 inch Color Monitor,ColorMeg Inc.,10,$319.00,2013-02-20
P1114590,R3000 Color Laser Printer,Connex,5,$699.00,2013-01-22
```

I am using the below code to do so

```
insert overwrite table product
SELECT  
  regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^,]*),?){1}', 1) ProdNo,  
  regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^,]*),?){2}', 1) ProdName,  
  regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^,]*),?){3}', 1) ProdMfg,
  regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^,]*),?){4}', 1) ProdQOH,
  regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^,]*),?){5}', 1) ProdPrice,
  regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^,]*),?){6}', 1) ProdNextShipDate

from product_temp;
```

After I run the above code all the columns in the regular table are perfect except for the ProdPrice column which has all values as NULL. So how do I extract the price from the temporary table without the $ symbol and load it into the regular table? Below is the current output where ProdPrice is null.

```
ProdNo           ProdName         ProdMfg      ProdQOH  ProdPrice   date
P0036566 17 inch Color Monitor  ColorMeg Inc.   12      null    2013-02-20
P0036577 19 inch Color Monitor  ColorMeg Inc.   10      null    2013-02-20
```

Here is the product table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `product`(
`prodno` string,
`prodname` string,
`prodmfg` string,
`prodqoh` int,
`prodprice` string,
`prodnextshipdate` date)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.RCFileInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.RCFileOutputFormat'
LOCATION
'hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/sales_db.db/product'
TBLPROPERTIES (
'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='true',
'last_modified_by'='maria_dev',
'last_modified_time'='1488149236',
'numFiles'='1',
'numRows'='11',
'rawDataSize'='516',
'totalSize'='650',
'transient_lastDdlTime'='1488149304')
```

Thanks

Comment: use delimiter instead of regexp .. it would be more cleaner

Comment: When I run your query, I do not get a NULL for ProdPrice

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert text e.g. `$169.00` to numeric field.
Hive handle this kind of mismatches by inserting NULL values.
Change ProdPrice to string or remove the '$' symbol (and if other currencies are available, save the currency symbol in additional column)

Comment: ok so how do I remove the $ symbol and store only numbers. I tried \\$ but that doesn't work.

Comment: Please add the `product` table definition to the post

Comment: I have added the product table definition. Please check.

Comment: (1) Have you changed the type of `ProdPrice`? (2) I think it would make more sense to use a decimal value here

Answer (score 0):

```
insert overwrite table product    
select  val[0],val[1],val[2],val[3],val[4],val[5]           
from   (select split (col_value,',') as val from product_temp) t
```

---

#### Demo

```
create table product_temp (col_value string);

insert into product_temp values

    ('P0036566,17 inch Color Monitor,ColorMeg Inc.,12,$169.00,2013-02-20')
   ,('P0036577,19 inch Color Monitor,ColorMeg Inc.,10,$319.00,2013-02-20')
   ,('P1114590,R3000 Color Laser Printer,Connex,5,$699.00,2013-01-22'    )
;
```

---

```
select  val[0] as ProdNo
       ,val[1] as ProdName
       ,val[2] as ProdMfg
       ,val[3] as ProdQOH
       ,val[4] as ProdPrice
       ,val[5] as ProdNextShipDate
       
from   (select  split (col_value,',') as val 
        from    product_temp
        ) t
;
```

---

```
+----------+---------------------------+---------------+---------+-----------+------------------+
|  prodno  |         prodname          |    prodmfg    | prodqoh | prodprice | prodnextshipdate |
+----------+---------------------------+---------------+---------+-----------+------------------+
| P0036566 | 17 inch Color Monitor     | ColorMeg Inc. |      12 | $169.00   | 2013-02-20       |
| P0036577 | 19 inch Color Monitor     | ColorMeg Inc. |      10 | $319.00   | 2013-02-20       |
| P1114590 | R3000 Color Laser Printer | Connex        |       5 | $699.00   | 2013-01-22       |
+----------+---------------------------+---------------+---------+-----------+------------------+
```

Comment: I am using Ambari Sandbox. In that it gives null values. Can't figure out why.

Comment: Correct me if I wrong, but I assume you see the nulls after the population, when you query your target table. right?

Comment: Have to close for the day, see my other answer.